# Rich User Interface on Embedded Linux Device

Tags: linux, user-interface, embedded, touchscreen

I'm designing a user interface for a large touchscreen device running Linux.  What would be the best toolkit/developer kit/SDK to use?  The only requirement is that its able to run on a semi-low performace device, and that there is a Linux version.

Nice-to-haves would be build in support for effects/animations and a modern look-and-feel, but they are not necessary.

I'm looking at Adobe Flex/AIR already, but I'm not sure if the device will meet the minimum specs.

Answer (score 4):

Try QTopia (http://trolltech.com/products/qtopia)
It's from the same stable as the popular Qt desktop toolkit.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Mopoke, QTopia is what you want.

- It has support from some graphics hardware (2d and 3d), and can also use the kernel framebuffer device if that's all you need.
- It's based on Qt, a very well-designed object-oriented GUI framework
- It's available for both open-source and commercial projects, although closed-source projects need to pay a license fee.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out whatever tool-kits are used for the [Chumby](http://www.chumby.com/).  It's a completely open-source Linux device (open schematic, open source software, etc) with a very rich user-interface (color touch-screen, builtin wifi, USB ports, etc).  I believe it's user-submitted "applications" are Adobe Flex/Flash based but there are a variety of open "hacks" including [a port of Quake](http://www.bunniestudios.com/blog/?p=262) that can be easily downloaded and run.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Disko](http://diskohq.com).

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Clutter.](http://www.clutter-project.org/)

Answer (score 0):

QTopia is indeed a good option; others are [DirectFB](http://www.directfb.org/),  and of course X11 generally running [Matchbox](http://matchbox-project.org/).

Answer (score 0):

CodeTyphon can let you easily code, visually design and cross compile GUI touch screen applications for embedded linux.

http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=96&catid=68&Itemid=147